# Georeference an image in WGS84 where I have the center lat/lon and image dimensions

Tags: python, georeferencing, wgs84, rasterio

I have a drone image which I have warped into the proper orientation and shape and now I'm trying to georeference this image. My image pixels are 0.2 meters, my image dimensions are 750x750 pixels, the center coordinate is 34.7150963, -76.6732313, and the x axis runs west to east and y axis runs north to south. I've provided code on my attempt but it may well be the wrong approach and really I just need to georeference this image based on the above parameters.

[image]

I've tried many approaches with `rasterio` such as trying to estimate the corner positions based on the offset from the center and then using the `rasterio.transform.from_bounds()` function. I found the bounds by estimating the offset in lat/lon based on 750 pixels*0.2m then divided by half to get the offset in meters from the center. I then tried to calculate lat/lon offsets from these offsets in meters but it seems to lead to a lot of error. There has got to be a simpler way to just georeference an image based on a center coordinate when it is already projected for WGS84.

First to get the coordinates of the corners of the image bases on a conversion from meters to lat/lon:

```
import math
scaling = 0.2 # pix size in meters

def calc_lat_lon(lat, lon, dn, de):
    #Earth’s radius, sphere
    R=6378137

    #Coordinate offsets in radians
    dLat = dn/R
    dLon = de/(R*math.cos(math.pi*lat/180))

    #OffsetPosition, decimal degrees
    lat1 = lat + dLat * 180/math.pi
    lon1 = lon + dLon * 180/math.pi
    return(lat1,lon1,0)
    
def output_corners(camera_lat, camera_lon, offset):
    #Position, decimal degrees
    lat = img.latitude
    lon = img.longitude

    top_left = calc_lat_lon(lat, lon, offset, -offset) # top left corner
    top_right = calc_lat_lon(lat, lon, offset, offset) # top right corner
    bottom_right = calc_lat_lon(lat, lon, -offset, offset) # bottom right corner
    bottom_left = calc_lat_lon(lat, lon, -offset, -offset) # bottom left corner
    
    return(np.array(top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left))

coords = output_corners(img.latitude, img.longitude, img.shape[0] * scaling / 2)
```

`coords` returns:

```
array([[ 34.71577004, -76.67405094,   0.        ],
       [ 34.71577004, -76.67241166,   0.        ],
       [ 34.71442256, -76.67241166,   0.        ],
       [ 34.71442256, -76.67405094,   0.        ]])
```

Then to do the actual transform and try to georeference:

```
n = np.max(coords[:,0]) # max latitude aka north
s = np.min(coords[:,0]) # min lat aka south
w = np.min(coords[:,1]) # max lon aka west
e = np.max(coords[:,1]) # min lon aka east
    
import rasterio
from rasterio.warp import reproject
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

with rasterio.Env():
    
    # open the original image to get some of the basic metadata
    with rasterio.open(path_name, 'r') as src:
        profile = src.profile

        dst_crs = "EPSG:4326"

        tsfm = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(w, s, e, n, 750, 750)

        profile.update(
            dtype=rasterio.uint16,
            transform = tsfm,
            crs=dst_crs,
            width=img.shape[0],
            height=img.shape[1]
        )

        print(profile)

        with rasterio.open('new_georef_img.tif', 'w', **profile) as dst:
            dst.write(img.astype(rasterio.uint16), 1)
```

But again this leads to a fair amount of error and when I do this transform with GCPs or with other methods they all differ and lead to error so I'm looking for help in a better approach.

Comment: You might be able to fumble through with Cartesian coordinates for a very small raster in a very flat area but the correct way to georeference rasters from an aerial platform involves orthorectification https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/insider/what-is-orthorectified-imagery/ which drapes your image over a surface to establish correct pixel to ground relationship. A good GIS focused drone software package like OpenDroneMap https://www.opendronemap.org/ should help you produce a satisfactory result if you have all the coefficients.

Comment: These images are all of the ocean so it will be perfectly flat ( I just included that example image to show some contrast) and the image sizes will be ~40x60 meters. Do you think that will lead to much error in this approach? I typically use Pix4D or OpenDroneMap with my drone imagery but these images don't have enough overlap and the ocean surface changes too much to properly find keypoints for Structure from Motion algorithms. I'm actually starting to think most of my error is from the IMU measurements rather than my code.